# Eclipse runs previous compiled test classes, unless I manually save the changes (ctrl + s) when running tests

Tags: java, eclipse

I have these code

```java
@Test 
void test(){
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

the test  passes and
when I changed it to

```java
@Test 
void test(){
    assertTrue(false);
}
```

it passes when it should not, but when I press (ctrl + s) and run the test again, it fails.

Comment: It sounds like you are not running the version of the test you think you are running. Save your buffers before you run anything so you are certain about what is executing.

Comment: Sure, this is the expected behavior. When _Project > Build Automatically_ is enabled (which is the case by default), your code will be compiled on save. When launching and when there are changes that has not yet been saved, by default a dialog will warn you and give you the option to save them. You can change this behavior in the preferences _Run/Debug > Launching_ by setting _Save required dirty editors before launching_ to _Always_ instead of _Never_ or _Prompt_ (default).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on the **wrong assumption** that even the changes that have **not yet been saved should be** compiled and **run**. In fact, only what has been saved will be compiled and then can be run.

To avoid manually saving of not yet saved changes, in the **preferences **Run/Debug > Launching**** set ***Save required dirty editors before launching*** to ***Always*** instead of to *Never* or *Prompt* (default).